# Speech recognition adding recognized speech to a string

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

What I've been trying to do for over a week now is to enable custom searches on the web via the use of speech recognition. what I want is so that when I speak for a web search my program would add the recognized speech and append a string which i can then add to the end of a url in order to search the web

here is the current code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;


namespace AID
{


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        SpeechRecognitionEngine reg = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string test = "12345".ToString().Replace("123", "");
            s.Speak("booting up");
            s.Speak("AID online");
            s.Speak("Hello sir, how may i assist you?");
            string[] commands = { "hello AID", "what are you", "how are you", "what's the time", "open music", "sing me a song", "thank you AID", "what does AID mean", "Tell me a joke", "i need to take notes", "i want to search the web" 
            ,"i want to check my mail","run lol","the yogscast","calabrate voice","where are you","tell me the truth","aid wakeup","aid exit","Who is bad"};
            reg.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            reg.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(commands))));
            reg.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            reg.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(rec);


        }

        public string time()
        {
            DateTime n = DateTime.Now;
            string o = n.GetDateTimeFormats('t')[0];
            return o;
        }

        public void rec(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs x)
        {

            string recString = x.Result.Text;
            switch(recString)
            {
                case "hello AID":
                    s.Speak("Hello sir");
                    break;
                case "how are you":
                    s.Speak("I'm good, how are you?");
                    break;
                case "what's the time":
                    s.Speak(time());
                    break;
                case "open music":
                    s.Speak("on it sir");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("wmplayer.exe");
                    break;
                case "sing me a song":
                    s.Speak("im a little tea pot short and stout here is my handle here is my spout if you poor me over hear me shout tip me up and poor me out");
                    break;
                case "thank you AID":
                    s.Speak("you are very welcome sir ");
                    break;
                case "what are you":
                    s.Speak("I am AID");
                    break;
                case "what does AID mean":
                    s.Speak("Aid means assistance and intelligent device");
                    break;
                case "Tell me a joke":
                    s.Speak("I like my relationships like I like my source, open");
                    break;
                case "i need to take notes":
                    s.Speak("opening notepad now sir");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe");
                    break;
                case "i want to search the web":
                    s.Speak("What do you wish to search sir");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" );
                    break;
                case "i want to check my mail":
                    s.Speak("opening your inbox now sir");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox");
                    break;
                case "run lol":
                    s.Speak("opening league of legends now sir");                  
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\lol.launcher.exe");
                    break;
                case "the yogscast":
                    s.Speak("opening the yogscast youtube channel now sir");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.youtube.com/user/BlueXephos");
                    break;
                case "calabrate voice":
                    s.Speak("voice calabration complete");
                    break;
                case "where are you":
                    s.Speak("Im here");
                    break;
                case "tell me the truth":
                    s.Speak("the truth is all but lies ");
                    break;
                case "aid wakeup":
                    s.Speak("Awake and awaiting further instruction sir");
                    break;     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to develop text-to-speech or voice recognition in your application. Not so long ago, Microsoft presented [Project Oxford](https://www.projectoxford.ai/speech) on Build conference that can do both those things.

Try it in a [Live Demo](https://www.projectoxford.ai/demo/speech#recognition).

It uses REST API so you need an Internet access to use this service. For text-to-speech you basically send text to that service and you download sound file which you'll just play. For voice recognition, it's the other way around, you send an audio file and receive a recognized text.

I don't have experience with this, but I believe you can find all information you need in the [documentation](http://www.projectoxford.ai/doc/speech/overview).

Comment: Thats no help but thanks its not sending like about sending it, its more appending a string to the recognized words spoken into the mic to then add the string onto the end of the url